# connection string for c#.net to mysql database connectivity

Tags: c#, mysql

There is a mysql database stored in my server at ip : 50.62.82.45 , Name of database is : detail_admin , user id is : welcome , password is : hello , then what connection string will be for me to access and fire query on sever database of mysql

I have tried this but it was not working

```
server = "50.62.82.45";
            database = "detail_admin";
            uid = "welcome";
            password = "hello";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

(mysql-connector-net-6.0.7-src.zip) this driver I have used for connectivity

Comment: I hope it's not the real password.

Comment: @Guillaume: Yaa it's not real

Comment: @Adriano: I have used (mysql-connector-net-6.0.7-src.zip) driver.

Comment: Is that IP address "dummy" or is it the real one? Is it accessible (be sure firewall doesn't block default 3306 port)? What do you mean with "not working"? Which error message you get? (cannot contact server? invalid credentials? something else?)

Comment: @Adriano:A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)  
This error I have got!

Comment: It's the error message for a connection to **MICROSOFT SQL SERVER** (via named pipes), not for a TCP connection to MySQL! Are you sure you're instantiating the **correct driver** (right: MySqlConnection, wrong SqlConnection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string myConnectionString = "SERVER=50.62.82.38;" +
                            "DATABASE=admin_urja;" +
                            "UID=welcome" +
                            "PASSWORD=hello;";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
```

Comment: Hi Kevan you miss "; " after at UID end